# MSVCR100.DLL not found on Android Studio launch

Tags: android, android-studio, windows, msvcr100.dll

I have just installed Android Studio and tried to launch it. But appears the following message and it doesn't start:

> MSVCR100.DLL not found

Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?  And what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That library belongs to Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Installing the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package" will solve your problem.

Depending on the version of your operating system, you should download the appropriate file:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=14632)